# Appendix wrong hyperlink in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, appendix, hyperlink

When I click on Appendix in the Table of Contents, it directs me to the Bibliography, it should direct me to the Appendix. How could I solve resolve it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%---------------------------------
\hypersetup{
    unicode=true,
    pdftitle={},
    pdfauthor={},
    pdfsubject={},
    pdfcreator={},
    pdfkeywords={},
    pdfnewwindow=true,        
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=red,
    filecolor=black,
    urlcolor=cyan
}
%---------------------------------

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{benner2005synthetic,
  title={Synthetic biology},
  author={Benner, Steven A and Sismour, A Michael},
  journal={Nature reviews genetics},
  volume={6},
  number={7},
  pages={533--543},
  year={2005},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group UK London}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\cite{benner2005synthetic}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
\refstepcounter{chapter}
\renewcommand\thesection{A.\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand\thefigure{A.\arabic{figure}}
\appendix
\chapter*{Appendix}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Show an example that can be actually compiled and tested. Remove all references to local files.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have just edited my question

Comment: sorry but I don't want to have to create four different files for such a question. Try to move everything into one document and remove unneeded packages.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have just edited, now it is very short.

Comment: move the `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}` behind the \chapter*{Appendix}, the anchor is there. Why are you doing `\refstepcounter{chapter}`?

Comment: now that is working, thanks